# How to create an empty floppy image with VirtualBox Windows guest?

Tags: virtualbox

Is there a way to create empty floppy disk images, which I can use with VirtualBox?

The client is Windows XP.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Linux:

```
fallocate -l 1474560 myimage.vfd
```

Linux & other Unix-like systems:

```
head -c 1474560 /dev/zero > myimage.vfd
```

Windows:

```
fsutil file createnew myimage.vfd 1474560
```

You'll have an empty "1.44 MB" image. Attach it to VirtualBox and format through "My Computer" in the guest.

---

If you want to format the image on the host system or to copy files into it, use `mkfs.vfat` + `mount -o loop` on Linux, and [VFD](http://vfd.sourceforge.net/) on Windows.  Note that official build of VFD "works only on 32 bit systems" as of version 2.1, but there are alternative builds available.

Linux:

```
mkfs.vfat myimage.vfd
sudo mount -o loop myimage.vfd /mnt
...
sudo umount /mnt
```

Windows:

```
vfd open 0: myimage.vfd
vfd format 0:
...
vfd close 0:
```

Windows, create, format and mount in one command:

```
vfd open 0: myimage.vfd /new /1.44
```

Comment: fsutil file createnew myimage.vfd 1474560 did the trick

Comment: Thanks. Here is a Gist with the virtual floppy + data adition https://gist.github.com/iamsortiz/1bdb9774832ea65855b2dc1b9b4ee8dc feel free use (or link) as much as you want in the answer if you think it's worth it.

Comment: Linux commands also works fine on WSL2 so I didn't need VFD at all. I just had to add `-x` to the `fallocate` command because looks like Windows file system doesn't support the same symbolic links as Linux. So the command is `fallocate -x -l 1474560 myimage.vfd`

Answer (score 2):

With Linux it is very easy to create an empty floppy image with 'dd'.

The thread *[How to create a floppy image?](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=1426)* in the VirtualBox forum contains a downloadable empty floppy image for you.

Answer (score 2):

I used to use WinImage for creating empty floppy images on Windows. The program is shareware and runs on 32-bit and 64-bit Windows 2000, XP, Vista, 7. Since later Windows versions have a compatibility mode I highly assume it will run there too.
http://www.winimage.com/download.htm **As shareware it can be used for 30 days without restrictions. After 30 days you have to buy it and register if you want to continue using it.** Since you only need one empty floppy image as a template, I would keep this image in a safe place, zip it, and unzip a copy every time I need another empty floppy image.

Just download the .zip and start the .exe directly, no installation required. Don't use the virtual floppy driver.

1. Run `winimage.exe` and click Ok.
2. Select New from the File menu.
3. Choose the format, normally you would select "Standard 1.44 MB".
4. Select Save from the File menu. Choose `.ima` as save format and choose a *filename*.

You can rename *filename*.ima to *filename*.dsk or *filename*.img or whatever you choose for your new empty floppy image.

Another fully open source method is to use vfd, but you need to install the virtual floppy driver first, otherwise you cannot use vfd to format the virtual drive and then save it to a file. vfd only works on Windows 2000 and XP (reported to work also on Vista) 32-bit.  http: // vfd.sourceforge.net/

Last but not least you could use Virtual PC to create an empty floppy image. Microsoft has an KB article describing the whole process: https: // support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/825098.

While Emulators and virtual floppy drives certainly are a possibility, using WinImage is the easiest and fastest way to get what you want. And the big advantage is that with WinImage you don't need to install anything.